# Storing Functions and Classes Names in an array and call it from same class

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with WordPress Admin Page.I need to store function name for different tabs.And apply them on different tabs.Tab names are got from site url by `$_GET[]`

I can Apply Function with like this `Foo::{$value['function']}();`
But The Class names in foreach should also be dynamic.Suppose I have Two Class Foo and Bar.Foo Contains Method - `generateSettingsPage()` and Bar contains `generatePaymentsPage()` Method.I need to require these methods as per nedded as in the following code in `foreach` loop

Below is my code from the function i am working within My class

```
class Foo{
   public static function adminPageContents(){
    $currenttab = (isset($_REQUEST['tab'])) ? esc_html($_REQUEST['tab']) : 'settings';
    $tabcontents = array(
        'settings'  => array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'General Settings', WP_SEVENT_SLUG ),
            'function' => 'generateSettingsPage',
            'class' => 'Foo',
        ),
        'payments'  => array(
            'name' => esc_html__( 'Payments Settings', WP_SEVENT_SLUG ),
            'function' => 'generatePaymentsPage',
            'class' => 'Bar',
         ),
    );

    ?>

        <div class="sevent-main-admin-container">
            <?php
                // self::generateSettingsPage();
                foreach ($tabcontents as $key => $value) {
                    if ($key == $currenttab) {
                        $value['class']::{$value['function']}(); //Something need to be changed here
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

    <?php
   }

   public static function generateSettingsPage(){echo 'works';}

}

class Bar{
   public static function generatePaymentsPage(){}
}
```

And I have the functions as per the tabs:

`Fatal error: Class 'Foo' not found`

Question is How can i successfully Run those function?

Answer (score 0):

If I were to ever use a static class, I would do it like the following and instead of using `call_user_func` just wrap the method in curly braces.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static function Init() {
        $tabcontents = [
            ['function' => 'A'],
            ['function' => 'B'],
            ['function' => 'C'],
        ];

        $result = [];
        foreach ($tabcontents as $key => $value) {
            $result[] = Foo::{$value['function']}();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public static function A() {return 'A';}
    public static function B() {return 'B';}
    public static function C() {return 'C';}
}

print_r(Foo::Init());
```

https://3v4l.org/ZTuaf

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
)
```

Also, you could do it like the following and just call the method, no need for the loop.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static function Init($tab) {
        ob_start();
        echo '<div class="sevent-main-admin-container">';
        if (method_exists('Foo', 'generate'.$tab.'Page')) {
           echo Foo::{'generate'.$tab.'Page'}(); 
        } else {
            echo 'Not found';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public static function generateAPage() {return 'A';}
    public static function generateBPage() {return 'B';}
    public static function generateCPage() {return 'C';}
}


$_REQUEST['tab'] = 'A';

echo Foo::Init($_REQUEST['tab']).PHP_EOL;

echo Foo::Init('Z');
```

**Result:**

```
<div class="sevent-main-admin-container">A</div>
<div class="sevent-main-admin-container">Not found</div>
```

https://3v4l.org/EORZr

**Edit:**

```
<?php
class Factory {
    public static function Init($tab) {
        $tabcontents = array(
            'settings'  => array(
                'function' => 'generateSettingsPage',
                'class' => 'Foo',
            ),
            'payments'  => array(
                'function' => 'generatePaymentsPage',
                'class' => 'Bar',
             ),
        );

        ob_start();
        echo '<div class="sevent-main-admin-container">';
        if (method_exists($tabcontents[$tab]['class'], $tabcontents[$tab]['function'])) {
            echo call_user_func([$tabcontents[$tab]['class'], $tabcontents[$tab]['function']]);
        } else {
            echo 'Not found';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}


class Foo {
    public static function generateSettingsPage() {return 'Foo::generateSettingsPage';}
    public static function generatePaymentsPage() {return 'Foo::generatePaymentsPage';}
}

class Bar {
    public static function generateSettingsPage() {return 'Bar::generateSettingsPage';}
    public static function generatePaymentsPage() {return 'Bar::generatePaymentsPage';}
}

echo Factory::Init('settings').PHP_EOL;
echo Factory::Init('payments').PHP_EOL;

echo Factory::Init('Z');
```

https://3v4l.org/mCqbB

**Result:**

```
<div class="sevent-main-admin-container">Foo::generateSettingsPage</div>
<div class="sevent-main-admin-container">Bar::generatePaymentsPage</div>
<div class="sevent-main-admin-container">Not found</div>
```

Comment: This works fine.But if i need to call a function from another class?Like `Bar`?for example I define another key `class` in $tabcontents and define a value for each? For example : `'class' => 'Bar'` . Then Can I call like this? `$value['class']::{$value['function']}();` ? But it is not working

Comment: When you say *But if i need to call a function from another class?* worries me, as if so you should rethink using statics. Update your question with an example of what you mean.

Comment: Isn't there any easy solution? When I use `Foo::` it works but when i use `$value['class']::` It doesn't work

Comment: No because, `{$class}::{$method}()` is not valid php, so you need to use call_user_func when the class is dynamic.

Comment: Could do `return eval("return {$class}::{$method}();")` ;p https://3v4l.org/kWCgM

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the way your trying to call the functions in `call_user_func()`, rather than taking this (`self::$value['function']`) as meaning call the function `$value['function']` in `self`, it is looking for a variable called `self::$value['function']`.  Instead you should use...

```
call_user_func(array(__CLASS__, $value['function']));
```

Here the callable is declared as an array with the class name and the function name as the two parameters.  The example from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

```
// Type 2: Static class method call
call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod'));
```